# Can an iPhone Accelerometer/magnetometer be used to detect when an object has reversed direction?

Tags: iphone, position, accelerometer, magnetometer

I am trying to code for an application where when an iPhone is attached to a device, it can detect when the device has reversed direction.

So far, I have been focused on trying to extract velocity information but now realize that 1) its challenging, 2) while very nice to have, not really necessary for what I am trying to do.

However, if I am primarily interested in detecting the point the device stops and reverses course, I was interested if the general opinion that this is feasible using either the iPhone's accelerometer and/or magnetometer. Am I being naive and I going to hit similar challenges down the road? Or, will it be as "simple" as detecting local max and min and determine which direction the phone is traveling from those points?

Thank you in advance.